# Seeking Term for Surjective Mapping of Graph Elements with Varied Valid Mappings

Tags: graph, pattern-matching, graph-theory

My student project touches on graphs and I need some help with choosing a term. I have a graph and I need to map its elements to a set of identifiers (surjective mapping). The closest thing I know is the canonical form, but there are a few differences:
1 the same graph can have several valid mappings - the task of unification is not set
2 the mapping is surjective, not bijective - an element may not participate in the mapping (if we are interested in a subgraph) and several elements may be mapped into one identifier (if they are identical for us).

The project itself concerns pattern recognition in a graph. Such a mapping is what you need to find for a graph (its subgraph) or check if it is valid.
A rough example: an isosceles triangle. To conclude whether the three vertices are such a triangle, it is necessary to determine which of them is the main one (at an acute angle) and which are lateral.

First of all, I am asking about a suitable term to describe such an mapping, but I will be glad to receive any tips on useful materials.

I don't have much knowledge of graph theory and I'm not sure where to look for such things.